# Help me identify species of fruit fly?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I found this fruit fly in **Pune/India**. It was about 1 cm in size. I explored info on several species in same region, but they were different in appearance, especially that black spot in middle of body.

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, it appears similar to fruit flies from Tephritidae family like [Oriental Fruit fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bactrocera_dorsalis) @Remi.b

Comment: Indeed! I removed my comment! +1

Answer (score 1):

This insect might be *Bactrocera dorsalis*.

[image]

It looks similar to this species based on the characterstic yellow spots, shape of the abdomen, as well as the light brownish orange stripes on the abdomen.

I had arrived at this conclusion by reverse-image searching the second picture that you have posted and observing the thorax and abdomen patterns. This image shows a very similar pattern as shown in your second picture:

[image]

The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bactrocera_dorsalis) article has quite some stuff to say,

> ***Bactrocera dorsalis*** is a species of tephritid fruit fly that is endemic to Southeast Asia, but has also been introduced to Hawaii, the Mariana Islands and Tahiti. It is one of the major pest species in the genus Bactrocera with a broad host range of cultivated and wild fruits.

Considering that you had found this insect in Pune, it makes a lot of sense to conclude that this is, in fact, the insect that you have found.

Comment: Do you know Indian flies well? Otherwise, it appears really premature to state "*This insect is...*". There are probably hundreds of related species in India, and the general color pattern are often very similar. I have an ok general knowledge of eg Swedish hoverflies (far from being a specialist), and based on this I would rather say that it is probably not *B. dorsalis* since too many small things that are often fairly stable seems not to add up. These include the posterior color of the scutellum, color of the femur towards the knee, distinctness of pattern etc. Might be a related sp. though

Comment: @fileunderwater I agree. There is black dot in middle of body which does not appear in any image of Bactrocera dorsalis.